# Partial derivative in understanding Neural Networks

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm very new to this forum. I'm learning the mathematics behind Neural Networks.

I have the error calculating formula which is the following:

$$\frac{\partial E_{\text{Total}}}{\partial \text{Out}_{y_1}}$$

The formula to calculate $E_{\text{total}}$ is:

$$1/2(T_{1} - \text{Out}_{y_1})^2 + 1/2(T_{2} - \text{Out}_{y_2})^2$$

The formula to calculate $\text{Out}_{y_1}$ is:

$$1/(1+e-^{y_1})$$

Now, I want to calculate the partial differentiation, which is $$\frac{\partial E_{\text{Total}}}{\partial \text{Out}_{y1}}~.$$ Could you please help me to understand the steps to solve this.

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean $$\text{Out}_{y_1} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y_1}} \quad \text{ and } \quad \text{Out}_{y_2} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y_2}}$$ and you are taking the partial derivative$$\frac{\partial E_{\text{Total}}}{\partial \text{Out}_{y_1}}$$
?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable : Yes

Comment: Then the answer of John looks right to me. Didn't it solve your question?

Comment: @ UnbelieveTable: Yes, Since I'm learning mathematics, It took me hours to understand this part of the second formula. $$\frac{\partial( {T1 -Out_{y1}})}{\partial \text{Out}_{y1}}~.$$ Thank you very much.

Comment: I see. Actually, you can just feel free to ask in the comment next time, and people here will be very kind to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the formula of

$$E_{\text{total}} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(T_{1} - \text{Out}_{y_1})^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(T_{2} - \text{Out}_{y_2})^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Partial differentiation is similar to normal differentiation except that you treat the independent variables as constants when differentiating. Thus, assuming $T_1$, $T_2$ and $\text{Out}_{y_2}$ are independent of $\text{Out}_{y_1}$, using the differentiation [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and [Power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial E_{\text{Total}}}{\partial \text{Out}_{y1}} & = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)2(T_{1} - \text{Out}_{y_1})\frac{\partial (T_{1} - \text{Out}_{y_1})}{\partial \text{Out}_{y1}}\\
& = (T_{1} - \text{Out}_{y_1})(-1) \\
& = \text{Out}_{y_1} - T_1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Comment: It took me hours to understand this. $$\frac{\partial( {T1 -Out_{y1}})}{\partial \text{Out}_{y1}}~.$$ Thank you very much.